# generic interface type restricting another generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, interface

How can I implement generic interface that restrict a type of interface that is generic?

```
interface A<T>

interface B<T> where T: class
```

I need the interface A<> to be restricted to interface B with any class type

I am thinking that it may look something like

```
interface A<T> where T : B<T>
```

or

```
interface A<B<T>> where T : class
```

but both doesnt seem to work

Any solution?

Comment: _How_ does your first attempt "not work"? I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but the first version misses the `class` constraint: `interface A<T> where T : class, B<T> {}`

Comment: *doesnt seem to work*? In what way does it not work? Are you just missing the class constraint in `A<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overengineering this. 
Simply do this:

```
interface A<T> where T : class
{
    B<T> SomeProperty { get;}
    void SomeMethod(B<T> param);
}
```

Comment: nice and simple